# Cannot reinstall ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: boot, server, windows-7

I made deep research on the Internet and unfortunately cannot found the answer. 
I installed Ubuntu 10.04.4 server (via USB) alongside Windows 7 (firstly I had to resize my partitions and then released some free space using EaseUs Partition Master), everything works fine, but then realized that server version doesn't have GUI, so i just deleted partitions created for Ubuntu, unfortunately because of that I had some problems with booting Win7 but fixed it. Then i downloaded desktop version and here is a problem, after starting computer and choosing boot via USB there is just blinking cursor and black screen. I tried with alternate version, version 13.04 and again server version 10.04 (just like in the first time) and it still have the same reaction. I am using Dell Vostro 3500 with nVidia graphic card. I found some advices but most of all was regarding when Ubuntu was just installed or there was screen showing functions like nomodeset or acpi. No one regarding situations before installation and when server version works fine in the first time.
I will be very grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem. have u tried other distributions? try fedora for a test. I installed fedora and then reinstalled ubuntu. worked like a charm.